# nextjs image into svg

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

How can I import a png image into a nextJS svg component.

This is the sample code I'm working with.

```
<Page title="Logo Designer" className="max-w-xl">
   <div>
        <svg id="logoDesigner" width={700} height={600} style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}>
             <rect class="draggable" x="4" y="5" width="80" height="100" fill="#007bff" />
             <rect class="draggable" x="18" y="5" width="80" height="400" fill="#888" />
        </svg>
   </div>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the image tag

```
 <image
        width="100"
        height="100"
        xlink:href="my-logo.png"
/>
```

make sure to change the `width` `height` and `xlink:href` based on your need